# How to Get IPAddress when User open web site using IP Address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am generating run time `<a>` link. To complete link I am using bellow code:

`string appPath = protocol + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;`.

But when user try to open web site from: `http://123.123.123.123/testApp` at this time my link is created with `http://myservername.com/testApp`.

I want the address what ever user enter.

If user Open open website from `http://123.123.123.123/testApp` the link should be

`http://123.123.123.123/testApp/Default.aspx`

and If User open website from `http://myservername.com/testApp` the link should be

`http://myservername.com/testApp/Default.aspx`

Comment: Side note: it would make sense only when your site is the only site on given IP.

Comment: I am not showing Live IP to user. so I have given Fake IP to user. They are accessing web site via IP address or site name.

Comment: Why not just provide a relative link, rather than trying to construct an absolute one?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : because it's generate run time, and not fixed, it's depend on values. Is any way to check request having IP Address or URL?

Comment: You can generate relative URLs at runtime. Just construct the `href` as `/testApp/Default.aspx` (or whatever is appropriate), and you don't need to know the host name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REMOTE_ADDR` server variable

```
string appPath = protocol + 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] + 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

Comment: I think you got it other way around OP looking for LOCAL_ADDR variable - user enters site's address either using DNS name or direct IP.

Answer (score 0):

One of [HTTP_HOST or SERVER_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) should provide you with information on what user typed to get to your site. It may be good idea to check with Http debugger what browser actually sends in case of IP address to make sure you check correct values.

```
   `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get the `IPAddress` of the user. 
But there is a possibility that you may not get the actual IP. There are many concern like `firewall` etc. Which may expose same `ip` for all the computer on the network.

```
    public static string GetMachineName(HttpRequest moRequest)
    {
        return moRequest.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null ||
               moRequest.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] != null
                   ? moRequest.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
                   : moRequest.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
```